# Solving a concurrent modification exception in a swingworker application

Tags: java, user-interface, collections, concurrency, swingworker

I'm writing an application in which some simulation is run in a SwingWorker. In this simulation some sets keep data which are modified in the doInBackground() method of the SwingWorker. This data needs to be shown by the GUI, but obviously this fails because as soon as the GUI starts accessing the sets a concurrent modification exception is thrown because the SwingWorker is modifying the same sets.

How would I go about sharing this data without the SwingWorker having to wait for the GUI to finish drawing the data? Do I have to copy the data and then publish() those? Won't this increase the amount of data by a lot (there is a lot of data)? Are there other ways around this problem?

Here's some simplified code:

```
public class World {
    public Set<Foo> fooSet = new HashSet<Foo>();
}

public class Simulator extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    private World       world;
    private WorldPanel  worldPanel;

    public Simulator(World world, WorldPanel worldPanel) {
        this.world = world;
        this.worldPanel = worldPanel;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            doSomethingWithFooSet() //structurally modifies the set
            publish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Void> voidList) {
        worldPanel.repaint();
    }
}

public class WorldPanel extends JPanel {
    private final World             world;

    public WorldPanel(World world) {
        this.world = world;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        drawWorld() //reads from fooSet in world
    }
}
```

Don't get me wrong, I understand why this doesn't work, I'm just wondering what I should change in this design to be able to do what I want to do: access the same data that my simulation is modifying. Does process() run on the EDT? If so, would it be possible to let process() update the sets in a copy of the world object which the WorldPanel uses to draw the data?

Comment: Posting some code would help. I'm *assuming* that by accessing data in your GUI, you mean that somehow you're structurally modifying your data set (*which would explain the reason behind your ConcurrentModificationException*). Is this really what you want to do over there? I would suggest that you look back your design and think about separating modification from mere *access*

Comment: No, the GUI just iterates over the elements. Only the SwingWorker thread is structurally modifying the sets, but if the GUI tries to access the sets while the SwingWorker is structurally modifying them this can be considered a concurrent modification I guess...

Comment: You're correct, the code and your update helped clarify your requirement

Comment: I would suggest using a BlockingQueue concept where your SwingWorker thread acts as a producer and your GUI acts as the consumer.

Comment: @Sujay Swingworker already have facility to act as a producer and a consumer: 'publish()` and `process()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simultaneously update and display the world object, so you have two ways out: do update and displaying sequentially, or clone data so that updated and displayed data are different. To implement the first variant, just do not use SwingWorker. In the second variant, if simple cloning the whole world is unacceptable, let the background thread compute not just the new state of the world, but also commands to modify the world's image. `Publish` that commands and then `process` them to update the picture.

Comment: Thanks, the latter worked, though I modified it a little bit to make sure it wouldn't draw the image for every iteration of the background task. I created a flag in the gui which is set to true when it is done drawing, after which the background task is allowed to change the image and set the flag to false. Then only if the flag is set to false (assuming one iteration of the background task is a little faster than drawing the gui) it will repaint the panel and use the updated image. It does add a little bit of overhead to the background task, but it does work pretty well. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure the draw-flag is really needed: Multiple invocations of publish are already accumulated into a single invocation of process, such that it shouldn't stack redraw invocations: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html

Comment: True, but I couldn't use the same data in both the background task and the panel (part of the EDT), so I have to create a copy of the data which the panel can use to draw stuff. I don't want to create this copy for every iteration of the background task, only when the gui is updated, that's what the flag is for. If I put that copying operation in the process() method I'm running it concurrently with the background task, I believe even on the EDT, so then I get a concurrent modification exception again because the background task is modifying the datasets again

Comment: Could be that I'm making a big design flaw here, seems like it, but at this point I don't know any solution other than using fixed size objects like arrays or using this flag to make sure the sets are updated without concurrent modification (sort of like a lock)

Answer (score 0):

I would add a flag in the gui, wether it shall show/access the data or not

initially set it to false and when your worker finishes reload the accessing part with switched flag

Comment: this would make computing and displaying done sequentially. This undermines the idea of using SwingWorker.